# how can I make sendmail go faster

Tags: sendmail, bandwidth

We've recently had an overnight ISP outage in our area which brought down our mail system. Now that the connection is back we are trying to push through the mail queue faster.  We've tried running the command to reprocess the mail queue.

It has it's own internet connection just to itself, and its peak usage is only about 5~10% of upload and download bandwidth. CPU usage is minimal, RAM is 75% cache, swap partition has under 3MB of data in it.

How can I make sendmail go faster? as the mail queue is just getting longer and longer.

Comment: You need to find the bottleneck, which may turn out to be the receiving side. Maybe you are trying to send out too fast for certain mailbox providers and they then blocked you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.  The mixed up routing for inter-site mail between mail servers, which we changed to backup internet connection during the outage, was not changed back. This was clogging up the queue with time-outs because I hadn't switched back to normal routing.  Mail was only being delivered internally in 1 direction.

Now we are sending email at 100% of our bandwidth capacity :)